# Should each client be given a tenant in Azure, while offering a SAAS platform based on Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Should each client be given a tenant (tenant, domain) in Azure, while offering a SAAS platform based on Azure AD?

Here is the requirement.

SAAS Platform

1. Client1 (contains **Users/Roles of Client1** and **Client1 admin**)
2. Client2 (contains **Users/Roles of Client2** and **Client2 admin**)

Comment: What is your SAAS platform for? What features does it provide? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

When you provide a SAAS platform to multiple clients, you need to create the app registration as multi-tenant and personal account type.

And each client should need have MSA account or AAD account because your application is protected with AAD.

So it's recommended to provide each client a tenant if the client is an organization or company.